# How can I add a search function to an ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

For our manuals app, we would like to add a search function. We need a SearchView in the actionbar, where you can type in some text. Then in the ExpandableListView should only the entries are visible, they contain the typed in text.
By clicking on one result, the searched PDF-file will be opened.

Thanks for reading (and answers).

**Edit:** Here is some code:

```
private void displayList() {

    loadSomeData();

    //get reference to the ExpandableListView
    myList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
    //create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
    listAdapter = new expSearchAdapter(Search.this, headersList);
    //attach the adapter to the list
    myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    myList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int     groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            **// Here I need to get the name of the clicked result and open the PDF**

            return false;
        }
    });

}

private void loadSomeData() {

    itemList.add(new expRow("Foo"));
    itemList.add(new expRow("Foo2"));
    itemList.add(new expRow("Foo3"));
    headers = new expHeader("Bar", itemList);
    headersList.add(headers);

    itemList = new ArrayList<expRow>();
    itemList.add(new expRow("Foo4"));
    itemList.add(new expRow("Foo5"));
    itemList.add(new expRow("Foo6"));
    headers = new expHeader("Bar2", itemList);
    headersList.add(headers);

    }
```

Here is my `expSearchAdapter.class`:

```
public class expSearchAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<expHeader> HeaderList;
private ArrayList<expHeader> originalList;
public expSearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<expHeader> hList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.HeaderList = new ArrayList<expHeader>();
        this.HeaderList.addAll(hList);
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<expHeader>();
        this.originalList.addAll(hList);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<expRow> countryList = HeaderList.get(groupPosition).getHeaderList();
    return countryList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    expRow rowL = (expRow) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    name.setText(rowL.getName());

    return view;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

    ArrayList<expRow> countryList = HeaderList.get(groupPosition).getHeaderList();
    return countryList.size();

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return HeaderList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return HeaderList.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
                         ViewGroup parent) {

    expHeader continent = (expHeader) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    heading.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    heading.setText(continent.getName().trim());

    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public void filterData(String query, TextView status){

    query = query.toLowerCase();
    Log.v("Adapter", String.valueOf(HeaderList.size()));
    HeaderList.clear();

    if(query.isEmpty()){
        HeaderList.addAll(originalList);
    }
    else {

        for(expHeader headers: originalList){

            ArrayList<expRow> countryList = headers.getHeaderList();
            ArrayList<expRow> newList = new ArrayList<expRow>();
            for(expRow country: countryList){
                if(country.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query) ||
                        country.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)){
                    newList.add(country);
                }
            }
            if(newList.size() > 0){
                expHeader nContinent = new expHeader(headers.getName(),newList);
                HeaderList.add(nContinent);
            }
        }
    }

    Log.v("expSearchAdapter", String.valueOf(HeaderList.size()));
    if (HeaderList.size() == 0) {
        try {
            status.setText(context.getString(R.string.noResult));
            status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}


}
```

Here is `expHeader.class`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class expHeader {
private String name;
private ArrayList<expRow> headerList = new ArrayList<expRow>();

public expHeader(String name, ArrayList<expRow> countryList) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.headerList = countryList;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public ArrayList<expRow> getHeaderList() {
    return headerList;
}
public void setCountryList(ArrayList<expRow> headerListcontent) {
    this.headerList = headerListcontent;
};
}
```

Here is `expRow.class`:

```
public class expRow {
    private String name = "";

    public expRow(String content) {
        super();
        this.name = content;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String content) {
        this.name = content;
    }
}
```

Here is my SearchView:

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
      search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
search.setOnCloseListener(this);
search.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search));

//...

@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        if (query.length() < 3) {
            TextView sInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusInfo);
            sInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sInfo.setText(getString(R.string.notEnoughSearchLetters));
            myList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            TextView sInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusInfo);
            sInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listAdapter.filterData(query, sInfo);
        }
        expandAll();
        return false;
    }

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    if (query.length() < 3) {
        TextView sInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusInfo);
        sInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sInfo.setText(getString(R.string.notEnoughSearchLetters));
        myList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        TextView sInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusInfo);
        sInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listAdapter.filterData(query, sInfo);
    }
```

Comment: Please post any some of code?

Comment: you can use serachview and edit text serach.. what are you use in your code@Gamecraftler

Comment: I use a SearchView

Comment: but better is edittext serachview@Gamecraftler I have implement this code using edittext  serachview..I have change this code yes or no.

Comment: You can use serachview see this link:-https://www.studytutorial.in/android-search-to-recyclerview-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will follow your tip. Can you tell me how I can get the name of the clicked result in my ExpandableListView, @User6829548?

Comment: Which model class getname to show result?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What means model class? I need the name of the clicked result.

Comment: Are you already define in expSearchAdapter country.getName() in filterData Method.What's wrong with you?

Comment: Exactly thats my problem: I don't know how to do

Comment: Okay I have run this code after tell you what's wrong..

Comment: I have run this code both ExpandableListView  work with I have serach C letter results is Canada and China @ Gamecraftler

Comment: Ok, thanks. But - how can i bind the searched letters (words) with the matched PDF-files in different directories on the device to open

Comment: You can serach with your PDF-files?

Comment: We need to get the name of the clicked result/entry. The PDFs open later but that code we already got. We only need to get the name of the clicked entry.

Comment: Can you help me with that? @User6829548